# Loop in PLT Scheme

Tags: syntax, loops, scheme, racket

How can I implement loop in  plt-scheme like in java-

```
for(int i=0;i<10;){
     for(int j=0;j<3;){
          System.out.println(""+j);
          j++;
     }
      System.out.println(""+i);
      i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks musicfreak, I am learning it. That's why I asked this question :) The scheme doc is not clear to me. But I think I will be used to in it soon.

Comment: Okay, just making sure this isn't one of those "do my homework for me" things. :) I don't know Scheme but good luck!

Comment: If it were a homework problem then you would see "problem" rather than "syntax issue".

Comment: removed salutation: "Thanks in advance.", next time do not include it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your example in Java doesn't directly map onto the Scheme language by just learning a few new keywords as there aren't explicit constructs for implementing a for loop in Scheme (unless you write a construct yourself!). The cookbook way to do this in Scheme is to define a recursive function that loops over a list. Here's an example of how to do a for-loop style function in Scheme:

```
(define (doit x x-max dx)
  (if (<= x x-max)
    (begin
      ;;...perform loop body with x...
      (doit (+ x dx) x-max dx))))

(doit a b dx) ; execute loop from a to b in steps of dx
```

Taken from this page:

[Guile and Scheme Links](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Guile_and_Scheme_links)

Here's another link to a page that describes the ideas you need to understand to translate loops from imperative languages to Scheme:

[Scheme Looping Constructs](http://schemecookbook.org/Cookbook/IdiomLoopingConstructs)

Scheme is a really interesting language to learn, you should also read the [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), which is the textbook formerly used for teaching Scheme at MIT.

Comment: No problem, it makes me think fondly about my positive experiences with Scheme in college. Learning a functional language like Scheme can make you a better programmer, something about it helps you think about elegant solutions to problems. 

Once you feel like Scheme is starting to make sense, I recommend checking out another "different" language, like Prolog. That's different from both Scheme and Java, and it can teach you different new things. 

Good luck. :)

Answer (score 13):

In PLT you can do this:

```
(for ([i (in-range 10)])
  (for ([j (in-range 3)]) (printf "~s\n" j))
  (printf "~s\n" i))
```

Answer (score 8):

The iteration construct in Scheme is "`do`", you can look it up in the [R5RS specification](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.2.4).

The example you gave would look something like this:

```
(do ((i 0 (+ i 1))) ((> i 9))
  (do ((j 0 (+ j 1))) ((> j 2))
    (display j)
    (newline))
  (display i)
  (newline))
```

`(do ...)` is a bit more general than what shows up in this example. You can for example make it return a value instead of just using it for its side effects. It is also possible to have many "counters":

```
(do ((i 0 (+ i 1) 
     (j 0 (+ j 2)) 
    ((stop? i j) <return-value>)
   exprs...)
```

Comment: to be clear, the second example with two loop variables will be tricky if you don't point out that all the variables are iterated at the same time -- one 'do' = one loop.  this example would correspond closely to the C loop "for(i=0,j=0; !stop(i,j); i=i+1,j=j+2) {exprs();} return return_value;".  Well, basically that's right.  Mostly.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'll edit the post later and try to clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting you to take a look to Michele Simionato's ["The adventures of a pythonista in schemeland"](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/index.jsp?blogger=micheles). It's for python->scheme, but, it's *really* well written and, more importantly, it's from procedural->functional.